# How do I access the contents of the list of eigenvectors and eigenvectors in the C++ Octave API?

Tags: c++, octave

I'm able to write a program that uses the C++ Octave API to find the eigenvectors of a matrix.  Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n=5;
  Matrix L=Matrix(n,n,2);

  EIG eig=EIG(L);

  cout << eig.eigenvalues() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvectors() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

which returns

```
(-5.46156e-18,0)
(-3.1176e-32,0)
(-4.86443e-49,0)
(3.38528e-16,0)
(10,0)

 (-0.18545,0) (-0.408248,0) (0.707107,0) (-0.31455,0) (0.447214,0)
 (-0.18545,0) (-0.408248,0) (-0.707107,0) (-0.31455,0) (0.447214,0)
 (-0.18545,0) (0.816497,0) (-6.72931e-17,0) (-0.31455,0) (0.447214,0)
 (-0.330948,0) (3.24211e-16,0) (-2.34737e-17,0) (0.830948,0) (0.447214,0)
 (0.887298,0) (-1.07469e-15,0) (-6.0809e-33,0) (0.112702,0) (0.447214,0)
```

From here, I would like to access these eigenvalues `-5.46156e-18`, etc., and eigenvector values `-0.18545`, etc., as floats.  How do I go about doing that?  I simply don't know the syntax.

Comment: I believe `eigenvalues()` returns a [`ComplexColumnVector`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d3/de3/classComplexColumnVector.html) who's methods should be able to get you the elements you need.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I found it; see below.

Comment: Take a look at Octave's [doxygen documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d8/d28/classEIG.html). You will see that `eigenvalues()` and `eigenvectors()` return, and what methods those classes have to access the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll admit I've never used the C++ Octave API, but looking at the documentation, it looks like they overload () to match Octave/MATLAB syntax, which is pretty cool.  (And a little terrifying, honestly)

For a matrix, row, or column 'x', `x(i, j)` will give the element in the ith row and the jth column.  (Note that this is zero-indexed, unlike if you were using MATLAB or Octave itself, which is one-indexed)

For a row or a column, you can omit the unnecessary dimension, so `x(n)` will return the nth element, for either a row or a column.

Comment: In MATLAB/Octave, everything is 1-indexed, I think to match math notation, which generally 1-indexes matrices.  (And because "ith row" sounds much better than "(i+1)th row")  But if your answer outputs as you've shown, I'm guessing they've changed it to be zero-indexed for the C++ API.

Comment: That's correct. Indexing in C++ is zero based, using the octave library as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to WhozCraig's hint and link, I found the syntax:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n=5;
  Matrix L=Matrix(n,n,2);

  EIG eig=EIG(L);

  cout << eig.eigenvalues() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvalues().elem(0).real() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvalues().elem(1).real() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvalues().elem(2).real() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvalues().elem(3).real() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvalues().elem(4).real() << endl;
  cout << endl;

  cout << eig.eigenvectors() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvectors().elem(0).real() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvectors().elem(1).real() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvectors().elem(2).real() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvectors().elem(3).real() << endl;
  cout << eig.eigenvectors().elem(4).real() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

which outputs

```
(-5.46156e-18,0)
(-3.1176e-32,0)
(-4.86443e-49,0)
(3.38528e-16,0)
(10,0)

-5.46156e-18
-3.1176e-32
-4.86443e-49
3.38528e-16
10

 (-0.18545,0) (-0.408248,0) (0.707107,0) (-0.31455,0) (0.447214,0)
 (-0.18545,0) (-0.408248,0) (-0.707107,0) (-0.31455,0) (0.447214,0)
 (-0.18545,0) (0.816497,0) (-6.72931e-17,0) (-0.31455,0) (0.447214,0)
 (-0.330948,0) (3.24211e-16,0) (-2.34737e-17,0) (0.830948,0) (0.447214,0)
 (0.887298,0) (-1.07469e-15,0) (-6.0809e-33,0) (0.112702,0) (0.447214,0)

-0.18545
-0.18545
-0.18545
-0.330948
0.887298
```